# Why do my equations say that an object thrown at $30^o$ with velocity 30 m/s has a $y$ velocity of 15 m/s?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity, projectile

I don't know if I have stumbled upon a genuine truth, or if I'm doing something very wrong. But here is my problem:

I am modelling the 2D trajectory of an object with constant acceleration using vectors. My objects initial velocity (V<sub>0</sub>) is 30m/s and it is thrown at an angle of 45<sup>0</sup>. You would think that this would result in the y component velocity being 15m/s but my equations tell me it is actually greater (around 21m/s) and that 30<sup>0</sup> is what perfectly splits my velocity. There are 2 things I suspect could be happening:

- The equation (as follows) is wrong (I can't see what could be causing a problem)
- V<sub>0</sub> is not split evenly between x and y at 45<sup>0</sup> (completely unintuitive but perhaps possible)

My equation for y velocity is as follows:

Vy<sub>t=0</sub> = sin(α<sup>0</sup>)V<sub>0</sub>+a<sub>x</sub>t

Note α is the angle (to x axis), t is time, and a<sub>x</sub> is acceleration (constant). This uses pretty simple trig, so I am confused as to why it doesn't work. Here is what it looks like on paper (a<sub>x</sub>t) goes to 0, and so is left out:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Try checking whether your velocity components are "perfectly split" using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: 2D vectors do not add like scalars, as in 15+15=30 m/s.  They add via Pythagorean Theorem, $v_{total}^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$.  Try your 21 m/s value there and see what happens.

Comment: This is really a question about trigonometry, not about physics.

Comment: @Ghoster ah yeah my mistake. That should be fixed

Comment: My best advice from teaching high school physics for 13 years: don't use "common sense" or Hollywood physics to work your problems.  Learn the actual concepts and apply those concepts as your teacher instructs.

Comment: @DavidWhite I know what you mean, however I don't have 'a teacher' for this, I am just trying to work some things out for 3D motion simulations I'm working on. Though you are right the reason I got these results is simple, just not intuitive from the perspective I had on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple math inconsistency behind this. While $45^°$ is $90^°$ split in half, $\sin45^°$ is actually greater than half of 1 (the $\sin30^°$ is exactly one half). The reason why the velocity doesn't get split into two "halves" is because that's not how Pythagorean theorem works. What you're thinking of is $a+b=c$ while I'm sure you know the real form is $a^2+b^2=c^2$. That means your model works properly, you just used wrong math in your head. Try not to think about it for a while and then return to it with clear mind, I think everything will seem correct to you too.